# Fades in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro

I'm watching a Logic Pro X 101 course by MusicTechHelpGuy, and in it he shows how to create a fade by ctrl-shift-dragging on a region. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to replicate this. Could somebody please point out the error I seem to be making?

Comment: Are you working with an audio region or could you accidentally be trying to fade a midi region?

Comment: Oh...there's a difference? ...that's my problem, thank you! Feel free to leave that as an answer so I can accept it. :-D

Comment: Just read these comments, on what is quite an old post. I have given an answer for your original question, to help future readers, even though it wasn’t for the actual problem you were having!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit fiddly; it just takes a bit of practice, as you need to click and drag from exactly the right place.

Here's a simple step-by-step method for getting this to work:

- press down shift and ctrl (you'll notice the cursor changes shape).
  [image]
- move your cursor to either the left or right hand side of the region you want to fade in or out. **It is really important that you see the cursor shape change again, to the one shown below!**
  [image]
- With shift and ctrl still pressed down, click and drag sideways to create your fade.
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

In order for this technique to work, you need to make sure that the Fade Tool is selected as your Command-click tool. It's possible that you have one of the other tools selected. Here's an article about this topic from Apple.
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: In the tutorial, he was specifically not using the fade tool...